# On Button Click, Confirm and Delete

Tags: php

I'm building a simple PHP file manager, and I need help getting files to be deleted.

Basically, how can I check to see if `.filename checkbox` is checked, where .filename is the class of the parent `<tr>`, as well as the name of the file, then if it is, when you click `<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete Selected Files" />`, delete the selected files from the `/uploads/` directory.

I'm not using any kind of database or anything, just password protected areas on the site. I realize this isn't the most secure way to do things.

I already have a script that populates a table like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>File Name:</td>
        <td>File Size:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filemane">
        <td><input type="chekbox" /></td>
        <td><a href="/uploads/file-name.ext" target="_blank">file-name.ext</a></td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload Files" /></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete Selected Files" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So I just need to know how to check which checkboxes are checked, and delete the related files from the `/uploads/` directory.

Comment: 3 lines of JQuery deletes all the files on your page ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cam use:
HTML:

```
<input type="chekbox" name="check_files[]" value="unique_file_id1"/>
<input type="chekbox" name="check_files[]" value="unique_file_id2"/>
```

PHP:

```
if (!emptY($_POST['check_files'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['check_files'] as $checked_file) {
        if(file_exists("path" . $checked_file))) {
            unlink("path" . $checked_file); 
        }
        //other logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['delete']))
{
    for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['check_files']);$i++)
    {
       if (file_exists($_POST['check_files'][$i]))
       {
           unlink($_POST['check_files'][$i]);
       }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using JavaScript and Ajax requests:

```
var chkBox, destroy, fileName;
while(chkBox = document.querySelector('.filename input:checked')){ 
    fileName = chkBox.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('a').href;
    alert('Removing file: ' + fileName); // send ajax request etc
    destroy = chkBox.parentNode.parentNode; 
    destroy.parentNode.removeChild(destroy);
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/E5WWN/3/